# Voronoi Diagram Edges: How to get edges in the form (point1, point2) from a scipy.spatial.Voronoi object?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, spatial, voronoi

I have spent a great deal of time now trying to obtain edges from the scipy.spatial.Voronoi diagram to no avail. Here is the main documentation:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html

If you create a Voronoi Diagram like so:

```
points = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2],
[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]) //Or feel free to use any set of points
```

then you have access to the following object properties:

```
vor.regions
vor.max_bound
vor.ndim
vor.ridge_dict
vor.ridge_points
vor.ridge_vertices
vor.npoints
vor.point_region
vor.points
```

But is unclear how to combine these to get edges in the form (point1, point2) for 2d voronoi diagrams? I know edges exist because you can plot the voronoi diagram and its edgres and vertices because you can do the following:

```
voronoi_plot_2d(vor)
plt.show()
```

[image]

which clearly depicts voronoi edgres - how to get a list of them and their starting and endpoints? Its okay if I only get the solid edges (not the dotted ones which go unbounded off the plot)

Comment: Simple answer to my own question for the quick reader: `vor.ridge_vertices` provides the indices into the `vor.vertices` array to get the edges.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the `ridge_vertices` attribute:

```
    ridge_vertices  (list of list of ints, shape (nridges, *))
        Indices of the Voronoi vertices forming each Voronoi ridge.
```

Each element in that list is a pair of integers.  Each integer is an index
into the `vertices` list.  So each element defines a line to be draw in the
Voronoi diagram.  An index of -1 means a point that is "at infinity".

Here's script that draws the lines of the Voronoi diagram:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi


points = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2],
                   [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2],
                   [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]])

vor = Voronoi(points)


fig = plt.figure()

# Mark the Voronoi vertices.
plt.plot(vor.vertices[:,0], vor.vertices[:, 1], 'ko', ms=8)

for vpair in vor.ridge_vertices:
    if vpair[0] >= 0 and vpair[1] >= 0:
        v0 = vor.vertices[vpair[0]]
        v1 = vor.vertices[vpair[1]]
        # Draw a line from v0 to v1.
        plt.plot([v0[0], v1[0]], [v0[1], v1[1]], 'k', linewidth=2)

plt.show()
```

It creates:

[image: Voronoi edges]

Comment: Wonderful! For future viewers, the primary insight is that vor.ridge_vertices provides the indices into the vor.vertices array and that's how you get the edges! Fantastic. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just found that `plt.hold(True)` is deprecated and the call would be superfluous. Source: [link](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12337)

Comment: @Martin, thanks for letting me know about the deprecation of `hold(True)`.  I removed it from the code.